# Inverse of a symmetric positive diagonally dominant, doubly stochastic matrix

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

I am trying to prove that the inverse of a $\mathbf{positive}, \mathbf{symmetric}, \mathbf{diagonally-dominant}, \mathbf{doubly-stochastic}$ matrix and having the following $\mathbf{property (3)}$ -   has positive diagonal elements and negative non-diagonal elements.

I'll describe the below definitions.

1)Diagonally dominant matrix - $|a_{ii}| > \sum_{i \neq j}|a_{ij}| \quad \forall i$

2) Doubly stochastic matrix - sum of entries in any row or column is unity.  i.e., $\quad \sum_{i} a_{ij} = \sum_{j} a_{ij} = 1 \quad \forall i,j$

3) Let $b_1, b_2,..,b_{N-1}$ be a decreasing sequence of positive numbers. The non-diagonal elements of the matrix satisy:  $$\qquad a_{ij} = b_{|i-j|} \qquad \forall i \neq j$$

Need to show that the inverse of such a matrix $\mathbf{A}$ will have positive diagonal and negative non-diagonal elements.

I have come till proving that the row sum and column sum of $\mathbf{A}^{-1}$ is 1. But not able to prove further.

Comment: I like this problem. But it may have been downvoted because it appears as if it is a homework problem and if so, you have shown little work and it is hard to tell where you got stuck.

Comment: I tried writing the system of equations that make up $AA^{-1}=I$, but did not get any leads from there. It's not homework, though.

Comment: I would attack this by trying to make a sequence of Givens reductions, while proving that in each the key properties are retained.  When you get to a tri-diagonal matrix, you can prove what you need for elinination reduction.  Then reverse the steps.

Comment: Let me try this.

Comment: Is there another approach which uses basic algebra? I havent been able to understand Given's reductions.

Answer (score 2):

That was an intriguing conjecture, but unfortunately it is not always true.

Consider a 5x5 matrix $A$ of the form you described with $b_1=0.15$, $b_2=b_3=0.05$ and $b_4=0.0125$.

The inverse of this matrix has several strictly positive off-diagonal elements ($a^{-1}_{15}=a^{-1}_{51}\approx0.0189$ and $a^{-1}_{24}=a^{-1}_{42}\approx0.004$).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a $3\times3$ counterexample:
$$
A=\frac{1}{17}\pmatrix{12&4&1\\ 4&9&4\\ 1&4&12},
\quad A^{-1}=\frac{1}{55}\pmatrix{92&-44&7\\ -44&143&-44\\ 7&-44&92}.
$$

Comment: This is smallest counter example I got! Thanks for your time.